# Using overloaded >> operator inside class constructor to initialise it

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading

I have overloaded the `>>` operator, making an object from a stream. I was wondering if I can use this in a contructor that takes in the same format as the stream but as a string. Could I use the `>>` operator in the constructor, or will I have to make code to split that line up differently?

For example:

```
Person::Person(std::string line)
{
    // this doesn't work
    this >> line;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Person &p)
{
    char c1;

    std::string forename, surname;

    if (is >> forename >> c1 >> surname)
    {
        if (c1 == ',')
        {
            p.forename = forename;
            p.surname = surname;
        }
        else
        {
            is.clear(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }

    return is;
}
```

An example input would be: Foo,Bar

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. There are at least two reasons for that. Reason number one: it should be `>>` instead of `<<`. Reason number two: the `>>` operator gets overloaded for `Person &`, but `this` is, obviously, a `Person *`, hence the overload does not apply.

Comment: Ah my mistake, was trying to generalise my code and put it the wrong way round. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
Person::Person(std::string line)
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    ss >> *this;
}
```